# Collapsing table cells in media query for emailing

Tags: html, css, email, responsive-design

I had to create an emailing html and I can say it is definitely a hard thing to do. Now, making sure it is responsive is beyond obnoxious.
I'm stuck right now on a seemingly unsolvable problem.

Here is the problem : I have a table with 3 columns (column 1 is a table, column 2 a spacer colum, column 3 is a table).
When I go mobile, I want the third column to go under the column 1. But no matter what I try I cant do it.

Please note that the display parameter CANT be used. That's very important. Google mail doesnt know what display means (...)
The only thing that seem ok to use are : float and align.

Here is my jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/cnw0o3wy/
the follow us and contact us cells are in the same table; that table must go under the first table. I fail to achieve that effect for now

```
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table align="center">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="align-top grey responsive">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="307">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr class="grey">
                                                <td class="align-top"colspan="3"><img alt="" src="images/mobile.png" /></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="grey">
                                                <td width="113" class="w113">&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="#" title="Apple Store"><img src="images/appstore.png" title="Apple Store" /></a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="#" title="Google Play"><img src="images/googleplay.png" title="Google Play" /></a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td width="4"class="responsive">
                                </td>
                                <td class="responsive">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="307" class="w307">
                                        <tbody class="grey">
                                            <tr class="grey">
                                                <td class="align-top grey">
                                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="151" class="w151">
                                                        <tbody class="grey">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="line-height:6px;" height="6" width="151" class="w151">&nbsp;</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="padding-left: 7px;" class="t-gris px12 bold align-top">Follow us !</td>
                                                            </tr>

                                                            <!-- 32 PX SPACING -->
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td height="36" width="151" class="w151"><img src="images/shim.png" alt="" height="31" />&nbsp;</td>
                                                            </tr>

                                                            <tr class="align-center">
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <a href="#" title="Facebook"><img class="social" src="images/fb.png" alt="Facebook" /></a>
                                                                    <a href="#" title="Twitter"><img class="social" src="images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></a>
                                                                    <a href="#" title="Mail"><img class="social" src="images/mail.png" alt="Mail" /></a>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>

                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="white">
                                                    <img alt="" src="images/shim.png" width="4" />
                                                </td>

                                                <td class="align-top grey">
                                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="151" class="w151">
                                                        <tbody class="grey">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="line-height:6px;" height="6" width="151" class="w151">&nbsp;</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="padding-left: 7px;" class="px12 bold t-gris align-top">Contact us !</td>
                                                            </tr>

                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td><img alt="" src="images/logo2.png" /></td>
                                                            </tr>

                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="padding-left: 7px;" class="px10 t-gris bold">
                                                                    50/54  <br/>92100  <br/>+33 1 49 00 00 00 www.mail.fr
                                                                    <span style="text-decoration: underline;">
                                                                        courrier@mail.fr
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="line-height:7px;"height="7" width="151" class="w151">&nbsp;</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: should this work in outlook? (it better shouldn't^^)

Comment: my emailing works already fine in outlook for desktop. I just need the mobile version to work which means mostly android, because it works fine on ios

Comment: Real Table columns will never go under another same level column. There is absolutely no way. You didnt find a solution because it does not exist. The only way would be to define the table with DIVs and use `display: table;`, but since you cant use display, this is not possible.

Comment: damn I wasted a lot of time on this already. How would you suggest reworking the html to achieve the wanted effect ? Maybe putting 2 tables side by side, but with no parent table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved my problem with the following lines :

```
td[class="responsive-grey"],
td[class="responsive-grey responsive-grey-spacing"],
td[class="align-top grey responsive-grey"] {
    float: left; width:100%;

}
```

basically float left on all three columns

Comment: i dont know why that works, because float:left is implicitly altering the display type of the element. so gmail does allow that, while it does not allow direct change of display? thats so indecisive...

Comment: actually it works and my answer is not complete. You also must specifiy 100%width on these columns. But then the content is floated to left and not centered. So you must put align="center" on the child table. It 100% works!

Comment: well it still doesnt work on gmail app lol! I'm not trying to make it work anymore